# Batch Calculating fields

Tags: arcgis-pro

I have a bunch of rasters with attribute tables. I want to calculate 5 new fields all with the same name (Avg, HS_Hq, TOs_UD, TOs_Hq, TOs_UD and using the same fields. I can do it manually but would take a long time.

So am wondering if there is a batch method to create the new fields for each raster that selects the relevant fields and calculates them. It needs to be a float, but all the field names are different but in the same position in the table. I haven't used ArcPy before, but am comfortable learning.

The field names are formatted like this, so different name, same position:

XXX1988 YYY1988

XXX2002 YYY2002

XXX2016 YYY2016

This is in ArcGIS Pro 3.0.1.

Comment: I havent tried it but maybe you can use [Iterate Fields](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-fields.htm)? Or look at [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252128/batching-python-script-in-arcgis-field-calculator). You can use arcpy for sure

Comment: Thank you, this helped me learn how to use the model builder and also saved a lot of time!